# New Query String Token not being generated even after CSS file in bundle is modified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4, .NET 4.5.

Here's the bundle I'm adding:

```
bundles.Add( new StyleBundle( "~/Content/css" ).Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css",
                        "~/Content/site.css" ) );
```

Here's the link to the CSS that gets generated from this bundle:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=8HZAB6C8ZnrIPYNFzMQKt0AR4AUsUYBjxPPkbGSRIZo1" rel="stylesheet">
```

My problem is I'm modifying bootstrap.css which is part of the bundle and it is not generating a new token for the **v**  querystring var so it pulls up the old version.

I've tried forcing an application restart to  get the asp.net optimization framework to figure out that I have changed this file but it's not happening...

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after another hour of trial and error this morning I was able to figure out the cause of this problem.

In the same directory where bootstrap.css was located I also had a copy of bootstrap.min.css from the original download.  So once I removed the .min file it has started to pick up my changes during the bundling and minification process.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Ran into a similar problem today. It turns out that the default behavior is to use the .min versions of the files if they are present. You have to remove the files as you have done, or set `usePreMinifiedFiles="false"` in your Web.config. Shame on Microsoft.